# How to get a modal to show information from a backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm creating views via backbone, and I'm wondering how to get a modal to show all the elements of the backbone view. For instance, if I have a handlebars template associated with the backbone view like this

```
        <script id="eventTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars">
        <div><h1>{{description}}</h1>
            <div (pseudocode display:none)>
                     {{title}} {{attendees}} 
            </div>

        </script>
```

And I have jquery code that when you click an event item opens the modal for that event

```
$("document").ready(function(){
            $(".event").click(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
            });
```

that opens this modal (pseudocode modal)

```
       #myModal 
               <div modal header>
                      <div modal body>
                          <p id="title">
                          <p id="description>
...
```

So I've tried giving different divs in the modal different ids, and using jquery I'd write the html under the ids with my eventTemplate properties. However, I can't figure out how to grab all the properties like "title" and "attendees" from my eventTemplate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the html of modal? who is $("#mymodel") ?

Comment: mymodal is the pseudocode modal, and the ids are the fields I want to change by accessing the eventTemplate fields.